# Checkboxes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make multiple checkboxes to be "checked" with mouse click-and-drag.
It works with my script:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(window).load(function () {
    $j(".filterset").selectable({
        filter: 'label',
        stop: function () {
            $j(".ui-selected input", this).each(function () {
                this.checked = !this.checked
            });
        }
    });
});
```

<kbd>[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3WL4D/)</kbd>

But it works only when you click and drag on the "labels" but not on the checkbox itself.
How to modify the javascript, to get this work?

Comment: There are no checkboxes in jQuery ?

Comment: Regardless of the code in question, but even if you got it to work correctly I don't think many people would realise that your checkboxes had that functionality.

Comment: Check a checkbox by "click and drag"?  What's that all about?

Comment: It works pretty sweet actually, in his defense. It's true nobody will know it's possible though :)

Comment: @user3586022 I actually agree with Daniel here,however nice job till now :-).

Comment: I know that. i will make an intro video for the special functionalities on the website. Aren't it the special functions, that make websites awesome? ;)

Comment: No, it is the content that makes websites awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figure this out... I saw that you already had a padding for each of the labels that overlapped onto the checkbox, so in theory it should've worked. The only issue was that the checkbox was actually above the label.

All you needed was some CSS added to the input checkbox to make sure the label was above it and it works like a charm :

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3WL4D/7/)

```
.filterset input {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Good find! Although I do hate the use of !important ;)

Comment: @JayBlanchard good catch, meant to take that out. Was trying it with a few other things before I came onto this solution and wanted to make sure the z-index was being set properly

Comment: Still, only the label is selectable here, you're just forcing an overlap of the label onto the checkbox. What if there were no labels?

Comment: @JayBlanchard very valid point. I'll look into it some more, but I cam up empty handed at first then I came across this solution.

Comment: This is likely a good solution for the OP as he just needs to appear to have that functionality. I'd like to do a little more digging for my own knowledge where selectable() is concerned. It may have to do with a checkbox's 'natural' CSS state, which I really have never looked at.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Take a gander at this function : http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Multi-Select-Checkboxes-Using-Click-Drag-dragcheck/dragcheck.js found it after some digging. Look here for the demo : http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Multi-Select-Checkboxes-Using-Click-Drag-dragcheck.html. Now this doesn't use the `selectable()` ui function, but it is still interesting nonetheless

Comment: Nice! And you wouldn't need the jQuery UI library.

Comment: If i use the z-index: -1; my checkboxes will be invisible in the website. And if i try to set the checkboxes z-index to 1 and the label z-index to 2 it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3586022 in order for `z-index` to work there needs to be a `display` style. So either `display: block;` or whatever you want your display method to be. You can also set your background z-index to something that is less than -1 because I suspect that is your issue

Answer (score 1):

I change the selector for the input element and it appears to work (although a little 'touchy')-

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/3WL4D/5/

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(window).load(function () {
    $j(".filterset").selectable({
        //filter: 'checkbox', // turned out to be unimportant
        stop: function () {
            $j(".ui-selected :checkbox", this).each(function () { // note the change
                this.checked = !this.checked
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what browser are you trying it on? because it doesn't work in chrome still.

Comment: I tested in FF, Chrome doesn't work. I tried to dig into selectable() a little more but it would appear that it needs further exploration. It does work in IE10

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jay! I testet in FF 29, Crome 34, IEX 11. But on all it doesn't work.

Comment: Which doesn't it work in? We may to dig into selectable() more to find out what is at play here.

Comment: All that was needed was some CSS. Take a look at my answer